# obtain the timestamps of database query in ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz

I'm wondering if there is a way to obtain the timestamp of sending a query to the database and the timestamp of obtaining the result of the query in ofbiz? For example, a client is vising the home page of ofbiz, i want to see how long it takes for the database processing the query. Thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Does your ofbiz and database reside/installed in the same machine. In that case a simple print function(to print time in millisec) before and after the database call(query) in the code will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

GenericDAO.java contains code (line 755 in  the version I'm using) that logs the query if it's over a 150 millseconds. This can be modified to print the query and it's time regardless of the time it takes or to whatever limit you are interested in checking.